# Como olhar para o campo que está sendo alterado em uma procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Criei uma procedure onde após executar ou atualizar em uma tabela a flag é marcada S de forma automática, fazendo com que esse item suba para uma integração e a integração após o retorno de sucesso marque a mesma flag como N, mas o problema é que acabei caindo em um loop com isso, toda vez que essa tabela sofre alterações pela integração e acaba marcando a flag como N a procedure vem e marca como S, pois ela está olhando para a tabela e não um campo especifico.

É possível olhar apenas para o campo que foi alterado, no caso o @price?

Abaixo está um trecho do meu código, gostaria de olhar apenas para alterações alteradas no campo @preço, é possível?

````
IF @P_TIPOEVENTO = @AFTER_UPDATE
 
BEGIN

  SET @CODPROD = SANKHYA.EVP_GET_CAMPO_INT(@P_IDSESSAO, 'CODPROD') 
  SET @NUTAB  = SANKHYA.EVP_GET_CAMPO_INT(@P_IDSESSAO, 'NUTAB')  
  
    SELECT  @PRICE=VLRVENDA,
            @AD_ENVIAMKTPLACE=ISNULL(AD_ENVIAMKTPLACE,'N')  
    FROM    TGFEXC   
    WHERE   CODPROD= @CODPROD  AND NUTAB = @NUTAB     


    IF @AD_ENVIAMKTPLACE = 'N'
          BEGIN
          UPDATE TGFEXC SET AD_ENVIAMKTPLACE = 'S' WHERE @CODPROD = @CODPROD AND NUTAB = @NUTAB
          END

   END   ```
````

Comment: Olá Gabriel, essa consulta seria a da "integração"? Não consegui entender a relação do seu código com o campo que você especificou "@price/@preço".

Comment: Use uma terceira letra para indicar que foi integrada. O ciclo pode ser N -> S -> I, onde I significa que estava S e que foi integrada.

Comment: eu faria uma tabela em memória com apenas os registros que devo tratar naquele momento, e faria um update depois com um join envolvendo apenas eles, assim garante o estado antes do update.

Comment: Eu faria isto por trigger , pois teria o controle das colunas afetadas , todavia por procedure se tem este controle também , como é esta chamada ?

Comment: Criei uma trigger e deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode-se fazer utilizando a função `Update`.

Exemplo:

```
if Update(VLRVENDA)
BEGIN
// Seu código
END;
```

Mais informações na [documentação oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).